# Security risks of running raw user input (code) in an AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Suppose we take user input from a form field. For argument's sake, say some python code; something simple like `2 * 2`, stored it as a string, and executed that python code from an AWS Lambda.

We know `2 * 2` is harmless code, but what if the user inputs something malicious.

What is the worst that could happen from allowing user input to run in an AWS Lambda?

Two obvious risks are

1. Can they access things (e.g. AWS keys/IAMs) that are *outside* the lambda?
2. Could they do any worse than perhaps deleting the file system on the lambda itself (which, presumably wouldn't matter since it's ephemeral)
3. Potentially craft code that chews up lambda resources.
4. Start other lambdas in a worm-like way

Are the three risks above warranted, or what risks are there?

The basic question I'm trying to answer is, is it fairly safe to take user (python) input and run it in a lambda without having a human manually review it?

Answer (score 1):

> is it fairly safe to take user (python) input and run it in a lambda without having a human manually review it?

Sadly its not and its **security risk**. The lambda code will have the **same permissions as your function** through its execution role. So whatever the lambda execution allows, your users, by running their scripts will be able to do.

Even if you execute the function now with basic or no permissions, later with time, you or someone else, may add some permissions to it **by mistake** and you may potentially end up with your function running with admin privileges living all resources in your account open to every operation.